# git add file over ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I do programming on an Ubuntu-machine, and would like to have backups on my Mac.

Logging in to Ubuntu from Mac with

```
ssh myubuntu@xx.dyndns.org
```

works fine.

This is what I would like to do on my Mac (to add .c-files to Mac git):

```
git add myubuntu@xx.dyndns.org/home/myubuntu/Documents/*.c
git commit -am 'myproj'
```

But the first command results in error:

```
fatal: pathspec ‘myubuntu@xx.dyndns.org/home/myubuntu/Documents/*.c’ did not match any files
```

How should I rephrase the git add command?

Comment: git add works on local files. If you're trying to get a copy of your repo on your mac, you want to use git clone.

Comment: `git add` doesn't do copies. You want to have two different repositories, and sync them using `fetch` or `pull` or `push`.

Comment: If you want to have backups of your code just get a GitHub or Bitbucket account. Odds are their storage is much safer than your two personal machines.

Comment: Code-owner does not allow to store on internet. Mac is automatically backed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you already have Git installed on your Mac, and that the Ubuntu machine's git repo is rooted at `/home/myubuntu/Documents`

```
git clone myubuntu@xx.dyndns.org:/home/myubuntu/Documents myproj
```

Then, each time you want to do a backup to your Mac, on the Mac simply execute `git pull`.

If you haven't yet put your Ubuntu files into Git, on that machine, do:

```
cd /home/myubuntu/Documents
git init
git add .
git commit
```

FYI, that will add all files in all subfolders to the repository, which may not be what you want.

Comment: after `git init`, you forgot `git add .`, otherwise there's nothing to commit.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I forgot the `-a` switch doesn't pick up new files.